# Using `ng add @ngrx/store` on Angular 10 gives error and adds Old version of ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, angular-schematics

On using the command `ng add @ngrx/store`, I am getting the below attached error.

[image]

However, the @ngrx package that gets installed is an old one `"@ngrx/store": "^1.5.0",`.
My `package.json` is:

```js
   // ...other packages
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
```

When I am trying to modify the `app.module.ts` file to add the `StoreModule` manually, I am getting the below error too.

[image]

The NgRX [official documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/install) says that they modify the below code using schematics:

```js
Update your src/app/app.module.ts > imports array with StoreModule.forRoot({}).
```

My question, therefore is, **Am I doing something wrong? How do I use the `ng add @ngrx/store` command and solve all these mentioned issues?**

---

### UPDATE

It is a known [bug](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2604) with the Angular CLI v10.

> Solution is to use  `ng add @ngrx/store@latest`

Comment: just use npm install @ngrx/store --save

Comment: Already tried that. No change. I am still getting errors when I try importing `StoreModule`

Comment: what version of angular are you using? ah 10. try downgrading. This is the problem with angular always releasing major updates every couple of months. everything just breaks.

Comment: Downgrading to Angular 9 did help. The `ng add` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Anyone knows how to fix the issue in Angular 10?

Comment: not sure. angular 10 just got released about a week ago. so it's still relatively new and a lot of libraries still haven't updated yet.

Comment: Got it. I did find a workaround for the same in Angular 10, have a look at my updated question.

Comment: @RICHARD ABRAHAM, thank you! I suggest you answer your own question in order to make it easier for someone who needs this.